# Itunes Connect - Test Internal tester, select version is empty

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight, provisioning-profile, ipa

I'm uploading with Application Loader an Application, the application is uploaded properly and appear inside Activity/iOS Builds: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byf4p4Su5JVwTUZjNkJyWWM1dFE)

But, in TestFlight/Internal Testing, when I tap "Select Version to Test" the dialog is empty: [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Byf4p4Su5JVwb00xM0xlNzIzUVk)

I have uploaded the build with distribution certificate and with ditribution provisioning profile (I have recreated all a lot of times...). Also I have checked that inside the provisioning profile appears: beta-reports-active